# sql server UPDATE combined with INNER JOIN with itself

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I found a problem with the following `UPDATE` statement in my SQL SERVER

```
UPDATE
    table_a
SET
    table_a.More = -1
FROM
    table_a
INNER JOIN
    ( SELECT column1, COUNT(*)  AS More 
      FROM table_a 
      GROUP BY column1 ) AS table_b
ON
    table_a.column1 = table_b.column1
```

Note that the INNER JOIN part uses the table itself.  After this `UPDATE` I am expecting some rows has `More` equals to `-1`. But I only got `1`s. I am 100% sure that `column1` has duplicates. What am I missing?

The problem I found out is that some guy defined the column `More` as a `bit` type!

Comment: please provide your sample input

Comment: Well, I found the problem. `More` is defined as a `bit` by some S*@#!# A@#$@ and wastes 3 of my precious hours!

Comment: Hi John, could you answer your own question and provide details of how you resolved this, It might help someone else who is stuck with this problem.

Comment: Ah, the elusive data type issue.  I've been developing a lot of import stored procedures lately and have been running into this a lot. Good work on finding that before you spent any more time at it!

Comment: That sucks! Feel your pain. People who use bit should be given a stern talking to - smallint is right there, and has more flexibility for when things (inevitably) change! :)

Answer (score 1):

I the problem here is the data type, in a bit type you can only have 1 or 0 or NULL also. Change the data type to int